Odoo 17 Getting attributes from custom component
I have a custom component called my_widget. I add it inside a form:
<field name="my_field" widget="my_widget" depends="field_a, field_b" />

Where depends should be captured from this.props. But is not happening.
My implementation is working but I need to listen the changes from that fields to change the value inside my component.
export class MyWidgetComponent extend component{
   setup(){
      // Setup
      ...
      console.log(this.props.depends")
   }
}

Already I'm using Odoo 17. I was reading the OWL docs but is not very clear.
I tried using this.props and does not nothing.

@toyota Why do you keep removing the [tag:odoo] tag? If you look at the [tag:odoo-17] tag guidance, it says "When using this tag also include the more generic [odoo] tag where possible." I ask because I've filtered out [tag:odoo] from my homepage but not the individual versions.

Thank.you very much. I though Op was using only odoo-17 instead of odoo.

js widget is not the easiest tool to perform that. you d better use the python way using onchange, that get applied instantaneously on  the display of your form's fields:
from odoo import api, fields, models

class TestOnchange(models.Model):
    _name = "test.onchange"

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    description = fields.Char(string="Description")
    partner_id = fields.Many2one("res.partner", string="Partner")

    @api.onchange("partner_id")
    def _onchange_partner_id(self):
        self.name = "Document for %s" % (self.partner_id.name)
        self.description = "Default description for %s" % (self.partner_id.name)

